# Prevent keydown() from being captured by document binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this, so I couldn't search it. Basically, I have a `keydown()` bind on `$(document)`. I'd like to `show()` another div, and have all keydown events be rerouted to this div and prevented from firing off in the document handler. Is this even possible, or would I have to put all my main keybindings on another div and work from there?

Comment: May b some code will help answer better.

Comment: I think it's clear enough. Plus, I don't have any code yet. This is purely theoretical speculation. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`e.stopPropagation`, or
`e.preventDefault` (depending on the situation)
Where `e` is the event.

Ex:

```
function onKeyDown(e) {
   doStuff();
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: But how would I ensure that my newly shown div gets the events first? Otherwise my document handler would stop the propagation and the event would never get to the div. Right?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville That's handled by event bubbling. Check this link out for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: The "adding of a character to an input" is a `textinput` event which doesn't fire if either `keydown`, `keypress`, or `keyup` is prevented. A better quirksmode link would be http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jeffrey. I'll accept in '4 minutes' (how much longer I have to wait after asking a question to accept an answer). :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I may not have the best answer. Wait it out.

Comment: Well, Starx's answer is clearer, but you answered first and said almost the same thing, so I'll accept yours. There's not a lot of wiggle room on this type of question for 'better' or 'worse' answers, just 'right' and 'wrong' answers. Of course, I could be persuaded to change my mind... :)

Comment: @elliot-bonneville I'm a bit late, but be sure to read my answer as well before leaving this page for good :-)

Answer (score 4):

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default behaviour of an event. What you need is to use
`e.stopPropagation()`, so that the event does not bubble up the DOM structure.

```
$(element).keydown(function(e) {
     // do the task
     // allow the default behaviour also
     e.stopPropagation();
   //^. BUT stop the even bubbling up right here
});
```

`e.stopProgation()`, can be bit confusing to grasp on the first but I created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Qvbka/) with click event to explain it.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
​$(document).on('keydown', function (evt) {
  $('#foo').show().trigger(evt);
});​​​​​

$('#foo').on('keydown', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt);
  return false; // this is very important. Without it, you'll get an endless loop.
});
​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7vYK/

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to even have a keydown event run on something other than an input or document, is to manually trigger it. You could have a global variable keep track of whether or not your div is showing, then trigger the event on your div accordingly.

Here's one such solution

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="showdiv();">Show div</a>

<div id="hiddendiv"></div>​
```

Javascript

```
var showing = false;

function showdiv()
{
    showing = true;
    $('#hiddendiv').show(200);
}

// Set up events on page ready
$(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        // If the div is showing, trigger it's keydown
        // event and return
        if(showing)
        {
            $('#hiddendiv').data('keydown_event', e).keydown();
            return true;
        }

        alert('Document keydown! Keycode: ' + e.keyCode);

        // Otherwise do the normal keydown stuff...
    });

    // Keydown for the hidden div
    $('#hiddendiv').keydown(function() {
        e = $(this).data('keydown_event');
        alert('Hiddendiv keydown! Keycode: ' + e.keyCode);

        // Make sure to stop propagation, or the events
        // will loop for ever
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

​
As you can see, the #hiddendiv keydown event is being triggered by the document keydown event. I've also included a slight hack to get the event object to the hidden div using the jQuery data function.

Here's a demonstration of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/DZecX/1/